# Proxy Authentication Failed error. [Java, FTP Proxy]

Tags: java, authentication, proxy, ftp, ftp-client

I'm trying to access an FTP server through an FTP SITE Proxy to bypass a firewall using `it.sauronsoftware.ftp4j.FTPClient` I know my username/password is correct because I can connect using FileZilla. I tried using `Authenticator`, but it has no use. Code:

```
import java.net.Authenticator;
import it.sauronsoftware.ftp4j.FTPClient;
import it.sauronsoftware.ftp4j.connectors.FTPProxyConnector;
...
    FTPClient client = new FTPClient();
        FTPProxyConnector connector = new FTPProxyConnector(String "proxyHost", int proxyPort);
        client.setConnector(connector);

        Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator() {
        @Override
             public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                       return new PasswordAuthentication("proxyUser", "proxyPass".toCharArray());
         }});

        System.setProperty("ftp.proxyHost", "proxyHost");
        System.setProperty("ftp.proxyPort", "proxyPort");
        System.setProperty("ftp.proxyUser", "proxyUser");
        System.setProperty("ftp.proxyPassword", "proxyPass");

        System.out.println("Proxy Accessed");

        client.connect("ftpHost");
        client.login("ftpUser", "ftpPass");
```

Gives me this error: `java.io.IOException: Proxy authentication failed`

Things I have tried:

- Using the alternate constructor `(String, int, String, String)`.
- Removing `Authenticator`
- Using just `Authenticator`, without the FTPProxyConnector
- Authenticating before setting the connector, and vice versa.

However, when I am JUST using the Authenticator, I get a different error saying `Connection timed out`.

Both errors occur on line `client.connect("ftpHost");`

**ANY** help would be appreciated.

Note: [The FTP Proxy Connector](http://www.sauronsoftware.it/projects/ftp4j/api/it/sauronsoftware/ftp4j/connectors/FTPProxyConnector.html)

EDIT: I found out that the proxy is a Firewall-1 Checkpoint -- if this helps.